# Clas variable declaration not working to with dynamic class loading in VBA,

Tags: excel, vba

Any help with dynamically loading of classes /variables in VBA?

I have an excel sheet and other few dependent sheets, depending on the requirement, on click of a button I am loading other sheets.

Say Main workbook -> Loads `sheet1.xlam` and related classes ( cls_one.cls) on click of button.

I am using below code to load `sheet1.xlam and  cls_one.cls`

Step 1: `Load Main.xlsm`

Step 2 load - `sheet1.xlsm`

```
    Set addedWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Type:=path,             after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count))
```

Step 3: Load `Cls_one.cls` dynamically using the below method.

```
    Public Function InsertClass(ByRef oWB As Workbook, ByVal className As String, ByVal filePath As String, Optional bUAT As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Errhandler

    oWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import filePath
    InsertClass = True

    Exit Function
Errhandler:
    If err <> 0 Then
        If Not bUAT Then
            MsgBox (err.Description)
        End If
        err.Clear
    End If
    InsertClass = False
End Function
```

Above code works fine, however, I have a reference to `cls_one` in `sheet1.xlsm` which never works, on loading or give error Undefined object error.

`Public Myclassone As cls_one`

this variable declaration is in `sheet1.xlsm`.

I tried flipping steps loading class first and `sheet1.xlam` next, but still getting the same error with Excel 2013, this piece of code works fine with 2010.

Trying to understand what is the best way to reference dynamically loaded classes in forms or other classes?

Also, I tried changing error preferences in tools -> Options -> Break on Unhandledexception.

Answer (score 1):

You can't early-bind to something that's only going to exist at run-time, *by definition* - there's no way that could have worked:

> ```
> Public Myclassone As cls_one
> ```

If `cls_one` doesn't exist at compile-time, then the module can't be compiled.

> *this piece of code works fine with 2010*

No. This piece of code works fine if it's not in any execution path that involves the module declaring a public variable of a type that doesn't exist... regardless of what version the host application is (this behavior is purely VBA, nothing to do with Excel).

That's kind of a hack though: a VBA project will not compile (through Debug -> Compile), but will happily run anyway if the entry point doesn't involve loading the module: that's because of the *somewhat-interpreted* nature of VBA.

Proof:

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit
Public foo As Something '<~ undefined, won't compile
```

**Module2**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "I can run even if the project doesn't compile!"
End Sub
```

You can run `Module2.Test` regardless of whether the project compiles, because `Module1` isn't in the picture at all. Now change `Module2.Test` to this:

```
Public Sub Test()
    foo.DoStuff '<~ expect fireworks
End Sub
```

When I ran this, Excel just outright crashed.

So the bottom line is this: you *can* reference a non-existing class in a module. The project won't be compilable, but if no code references the non-existing class then the project will be executable anyway, and the non-compilable module can then be executed in another execution context (i.e. from a separate entry point), after the class is added.

I would not recommend using non-compilable code for anything remotely important though, since doing that takes away the only compile-time validation you have in the VBE for your code - consider reviewing [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) inspections in that case (several inspections flag run-time error situations statically).

A better, more viable solution would be to reconsider the dependency chain and the overall approach.

Comment: thanks for the response -  still cant understand why work with 2010- also, I have tried loading class first and then other sheet where cls is referenced.  But still fails?